# WPF Window unclickable

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I've created a scoreboard application with WPF (C# and XAML) and I need to make one window totally unresponsive when I enable a lock on it via a checkbox. Meaning you can't click it, the cursor doesn't change  and especially the windows task bar doesn't come up when you click it. This Scoreboard is on top of a game, the scoreboard is the topmost window, but for some reason I can't make it completely unclickable.

I've tried IsHitTestVisible, Focusable, IsManipulationEnabled, ResizeMode, WindowStyle and set them all to false with no effect. I can still click the window and it brings up the Window s task bar and it kinda gets annoying when you have a game which should be fullscreen windowed.

What can I do about this?

**Update:**

Found the answer by changing some google search words.

**Win32 Class**

```
    //Rest of this code in located in the class itself
    public const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;
    public const int GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd,
    int index);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd,
    int index, int newStyle);

    public static void makeTransparent(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
     int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
     Win32.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
    }
    public static void makeNotTransparent(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        Win32.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle ^ WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
    }
```

**Event**

```
       base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

        IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(yourWindow).Handle;
        Win32.makeTransparent(hwnd);
```

Comment: I don't know about the idea of a separate score board. Why not create an image that is drawn to the game window like in most games? Or am I missing some point?

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to when user right click on the unclickabled windows, the window (or desktop) behind it, react against this event. And also what to do if we use other platforms like Linux or Mac-OS?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils They likely don't have control over the original game.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried IsEnabled = false?
It works for me on component and on window level.

Answer (score -1):

I saw this [blog](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/iersoy/windows-controls-and-wpf-usercontrols-inside-an-xna-game-project/) in which they placed Wpf control inside XNA game. I have tried it and its working, you can place your window and it will not appear in taskbar also, they have also given technique for fullscreen also